# changing the subnet on a DDWRT router

Tags: networking, router, lan, subnet, dd-wrt

I'm currently working on a bridged openvpn setup between two places. My home lan uses a 192.168.1.x subnet, as does the remote location (which i can't change the subnet for anyway) which results, naturally in ip address conflict. I'd like to know how i could change my home subnet to 192.168.0.x so that they wouldn't conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bridged VPN then both endpoints ***must*** have the same subnet.  You just have to ensure that each end uses different IP addresses (I would suggest that one uses addresses ending in `.1` to `.127` and the other `.128` to `.254`).

To change the subnet used for the LAN on a DD-WRT device log in to the web interface, select the Setup tab and change the settings under **Network Setup**.  This, and much more, is covered in the DD-WRT documentation.

---

What version of DD-WRT are you running?  It's certainly there in V24 and something similar should be there for V23.

---

Right, under *Basic Setup* you'll see *Network Setup*.  That's the default tab as soon as you select *Setup* so I didn't see the need to highlight it.

---

Changing the *Local IP address* is what you want.  Changing the *Subnet Mask* changes what bits of the *Local IP address* field are interpreted as the local network, which won't help you.

Comment: there's no such tab. basic set up has an option for setting router IP, but that's about it

Comment: also Sat Aug 28 23:26:25 2010 WARNING: potential TUN/TAP adapter subnet conflict between local LAN [192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0] and remote VPN [192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0] suggests i may need to change subnets on one side

Comment: v24sp1 - the options there are 

    * Basic Setup
    * DDNS
    * MAC Address Clone
    * Advanced Routing
    * VLANs
    * Networking

Comment: Probably in Basic Setup or Networking

Comment: i get Local IP Address, Subnet Mask ,Gateway, Local DNS

I suppose changing the subnet of the first should work?

Comment: ahh, i grok. Thanks for the effort, and i'd upvote this more than once if i could. You'll have to settle for 50 rep ;p

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a virtual subnet which enables something like this:

[image]

Since the process is a lengthy one, I won't post what to do, but I found [this](http://www.zimbio.com/Wireless+LAN/articles/2800125/Configure+Multiple+SSIDs+One+Router) tutorial on how to do just that.

In case that one doesn't work [here](http://www.pennock.nl/dd-wrt/Multiple_BSSIDs.html) is a second one to go off of.

**Update** After reading the tutorials a little more, it looks like the second one, might be a little more successful, but I'll leave both up.

Comment: Nope. I'm NOT trying to have 2 subnets in the same place. I'm trying to change my subnet so that i won't have a conflict with the subnet i'm using for a VPN

Comment: But you cannot when you have a bridged router.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest idea is to use fixed IP addresses.

For example, give your home computers an IP address that counts down from 192.168.1.253.
This is quite safe, as the remote network will probably go upwards from 192.168.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this to advise anyone finding this post trying to configure a VPN between networks or single computers.

If this is just a single PC that you are connecting to the remote LAN, Using a bridged VPN, I would suggest using getting your PC's IP address using DHCP from the VPN.  If you are connecting your entire home network via the VPN.  I would suggest using a routed VPN.  That way you do not have any conflicts.  With a routed VPN you do have two subnets.  One at your remote location and one at you local location.  With a routed VPN you do not have to worry about two networks having IP address conflicts.  Also broadcast packets are not passed through the VPN, saving bandwidth.