# How to create a private home network?

Tags: networking

I am new to this stuff so any help will be appreciated. 
We have two Win laptops, a Win desktop and an iMac connected wirelessly at home. I am learning about webservers and would like to host one at home just to learn/play.

I don't want to have a compromised webserver access our other computers - which might happen if I misconfigure something. Is there a way to make my existing computers still access the internet but be 'segregated' from the webserver?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Possible dupe of: http://superuser.com/questions/182651/how-to-create-a-private-home-network/182656

Comment: Please don't crosspost - http://superuser.com/questions/182664/how-to-create-a-segregated-network-at-home

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way, use two SOHO grade routers:

```
Internet Connection --- RouterA --- RouterB --- Home Computers
                           |           |
                        Server       Wireless
```

Answer (score 1):

Your home network should already be private. The external IP address you have will point to the router/modem and, as long as it's set up correctly, no one should be able to see past that to the rest of your network.

If you host your website on one of your local machines it won't be visible to the outside world.

It won't have an address like www.example.com. You'll have to access it via it's internal IP address - 192.162.2.23 (for example) or computer name (http:\ComputerName) [Thank's @harrymc].

Comment: Computers can also be addressed by their name as "http:\\ComputerName"

Comment: He might also be asking about the use of dmz? But I'm not entirely sure, given his 'just to learn/play' comment.

Comment: @harrymc -  I never new that. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DD-WRT flashed router you can create a separate VLAN.  See my post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/181694/changing-the-subnet-on-a-ddwrt-router)

Answer (score 0):

A NetGear Prosafe GS108T smart switch will let you set up VLANs, allowing you to keep different parts of your LAN separate.  I've been using this switch for a while and love it.  I haven't messed around with VLANs yet, but it looks straightforward.  The GS108T is available for less than $100.